# Looking for indexable, self-sorting data structure with multiple keys

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I want to store pairs of `<Integer, Object>` and keep them in ascending order by the integer key. However, it should be allowed to keep the same key for different objects in the structure so I can't use one of the standard Maps.

Furthermore, the pairs should be able to be addressed by an index. So if I want to address the pair at index 2 (the third-greatest integer value), it should return the object stored there. Afterwards I want to change the integer value, sort the structure back again and rearrange the indices according to the ascending order.

The number of pairs in this structure is going to be constant so I don't need efficient insertion or deletion, only efficient sorting.

Is there such a data structure in Java (or at least in general)?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit too specific to exist in a general library, but a data structure that can be used to solve this problem efficiently is an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) (that is, a self-balancing binary search tree (BST) where each node stores the size of the subtree rooted at that node).

Insertion into and deletion from this tree (we can define an update as a delete followed by an insert) would look exactly the same as it would to a regular BST, apart from increasing and decreasing the subtree sizes appropriately.

To get the i-th element, we start at the root and repeatedly determine in which child subtree the target node would be by looking at the number of nodes.

Any of the above operations would take O(log n) time.

If you're able to [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) elements with the same integer value in some way (e.g. using the corresponding object) the above would work as is. If they can't be ordered, it's also possible to have each node be a collection (e.g. List) of elements with the same integer value, and then, instead of the number of nodes, we keep track of the number of elements (i.e. the sum of the sizes of each node) in each subtree.

Note: If you can't find a library or self-balancing implementation, it might be easiest to take a working implementation of a red-black tree and modify that to keep track of the sizes.

---

If you'd prefer simplicity:

If you're happy with O(n) to get the i-th element, and O(log n) per update, you can, similar to what I described above, just use a `TreeMap<Integer, List<Object>>` (or [Guava's MultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)), i.e. have each node store a list of objects with that integer value. Then, to find the i-th element, you can simply iterate through and keep track of how many elements we've encountered thus far.

If you're happy with O(1) to get the i-th element, but O(n) per update, you can simply use a sorted `ArrayList` and iterate through to find the correct element and shift it to the correct position. The update can be optimised to use binary search, but it will still be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the same key for multiple entries, you should consider using `MultiMap` from Google Guava, for example.

http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

One of the implementations of `MultiMap` interface is `SortedSetMultimap` which can be quite useful in your case.

Comment: No, that's not what I want. There should be entries like:
    <1000,Object>    (index: 0)
    <999,Object>     (index: 1)
    <998,Object>     (index: 2)
    <998,Object>     (index: 3)
and so on.